# USB not detected with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mount, disk

This is what I got with

```
sudo fdisk -l
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 484214783 484212736 230.9G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       484216830 488396799   4179970     2G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       484216832 488396799   4179968     2G 82 Linux swap / Solaris




Disk /dev/sdb: 15 GiB, 16106127360 bytes, 31457280 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *       32 31457279 31457248  15G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

and

```
lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 230.9G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0     2G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   1    15G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1    15G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

I have tried to mount it but

```
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /media/milenko/flashdrive/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

With gparted,does not appear sdb
[image]

What should I try?

Comment: Remove the stick from PC, execute `tail -n 0 -f /var/log/syslog`, and insert the stick back again. Try to mount the filesystem *(just click the drive image in file manager)*. Then copy-paste the output of the command into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

will it mount in windows? I had this once and the USB's disk format was bad. Only solution was to use gparted to completely reformat it (hopefully you won't have to).

Comment: I am not using Windows at all,when I sudo gparted it does not show sdb at all.I will edit my question.

Answer (score -2):

Just a warning regards an attached USB device which appeared to be effectively useless: 'bad superblock', huge bad-block list, gparted identified it, but couldn't select it, smartmontools "read device identity failed", etc. In my case, a Seagate 3TB usb drive. I was just about to throw in the towel and try to do a hard-reformat, but decided instead to power-cycle everything, re-boot (but not re-mount the USB drive), and do a blkid to see if Ubu 16.04 could detect it. It did, I re-mounted it, and found the 2TB of archives I had been storing were still there, and apparently intact.

I'm assuming there is an intermittent hardware problem (due to periodic lengthy write-retries), and the drive is no longer reliable. However, still have a decent chance of recovering most of the archival data.

Update: Apropos 'smartmontools' & 'read device identity failed'...
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1334569

(The above link appears to provide work-arounds to the error conditions I encountered, specific to external USB3 Seagate Expansion Disk with USB IDs 0bc2:3312, using smartmontools.)